# Buscas no mysql - Letras com acentuação

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, phpmyadmin

Atualmente faço minha busca da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT * FROM cadastro WHERE nome LIKE '%são%'
```

Dessa forma não me retorna um resultado, porém, quando coloco somente o `ã` em maiúsculo `Ã` eu obtenho o resultado.

Assim funciona:

```
SELECT * FROM cadastro WHERE nome LIKE '%sÃo%'
```

Poderiam me responder como posso resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 0):

Mude o tipo de codificação que seu banco utiliza, faça assim

```
 ALTER DATABASE `seu_banco`CHARSET = UTF8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: O meu banco já está com essa codificação.

Comment: Dentro do LIKE, você irá utilizar textos ou irá concatenar com variáveis?

Comment: Nesse caso somente texto.